# Describe the equalizer of $f,1:X\to X$ as explicitly as possible

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Exercise 5.2.22 from Leinster asks to describe the equalizer of $f,1:X\to X$ in $\mathbf{Set}$, where $f:X\to X$ is a map, as explicitly as possible.

What level of explicitness is expected? By definition, it is a pair $(S,h)$ where $S$ is a set and $S\to X$ is a map such that $fh=h$, and if $(S'g)$ is another such pair, then there is a unique $\bar g:S'\to S$ such that $h\bar g=g$. How can one make this more explicit?

Comment: They want you to give an explicit description, not a categorical one. Namely, you should be able to specify an *explicit* set $S$ and an explicit map $h$ with the property (both defined in terms of $X$ and $f$), rather than just parrot back the definition of “equalizer”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin After your comment I realized that Leinster describes equalizers of arbitrary maps in Set in Example 5.1.12, and the exercise is about coequalizers (but I was thinking about equalizers)... I'll try to apply your hint to coequalizers as well.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is there a more explicit way to describe the coequalizer than saying that it is the set $X/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $\{(f(x),x):x\in X\}$, together with the quotient map $X\to X/{\sim}$?

Comment: @user634426: yes, you can explicitly describe what the generated equivalence relation is

Comment: I've posted a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305950/how-to-describe-explicitly-the-equivalence-relation-generated-by-r-fx-xx) about this equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

The equalizer of $s,t:X\to Y$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ is $(E,i)$ where $E=\{x\in X:s(x)=t(x)\}$ and $i:E\to X$ is the inclusion map. This is clearly a fork, and if $(A,g)$ is another fork, then define $\bar g:A\to E, a\mapsto g(a)$. Note that $g(a)$ indeed lives in $E$ because $sg=tg$, and $\bar g$ is the unique map $A\to E$ such that $i\bar g=g$.

Apply this to $Y=X,\ s=1,\ t=f$.

Answer (score 0):

To give a categorical construction explicitly in a given category is to give in terms of the concrete definition of the objects of the category. For sets, you give the elements, for algebraic objects, you give the elements and the operations; for spaces, the elements and the geometric or topological structure, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The equalizer of an endofunction $f:X \to X$ and the identity on $X$ is simply the set of fixed points of $f$. More generally, we could call the equalizer of an endomorphism $f$ and the identity in any category the "object of fixed points of $f$".