# How to describe explicitly the equivalence relation generated by $R=\{(f(x),x):x\in X\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Context: This is part of [Exercise 5.2.22(a)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf).

The problem is to describe explicitly the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by $R=\{(f(x),x):x\in X\}$ as well as the quotient map, where $f:X\to X$ is a function of sets.

I suppose I should use the explicit description of the equivalence relation generated by a set from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3305759/634426). If we write $x\to x'$ for $(x,x')\in R$, then the description says that $\sim$ is equal to the  set $\tilde{R}$ of pairs $(x,x')$ such that either $x=x'$ or there exist $x_0=x,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n=x'\in X$ with either $x_{k-1}\to x_k$ or $x_{k-1}\gets x_k$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ (with $n\ge1$).

So in my understanding the problem boils down to find explicitly all pairs $(f(x),x)$ with the property that there exist $x_0=f(x),x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n=x$ such that either $x_{k-1}\to x_k$ or $x_{k-1}\gets x_k$. But how to do this?

Comment: I think in this case it is easier to think of the partition related with the equivalence relation.  
You know how partitions and equivalence relations are connected, right?
In this partition, $A$ is one block iff 
$$f(A) \subseteq A \quad\text{ and }\quad f(X \setminus A) \subseteq X \setminus A.$$  
So $a \sim b$ iff $a$ and $b$ belong to the same block. But this might not be satisfactory...

Comment: How about just viewing the unordered pairs $\{x,f(x)\}$ as the edges of a graph, and declare that you're looking for its connected components? You can't really be more specific than that without knowing what $f$ is, and the actual exercise you're pointing to doesn't seem the require that either.

Comment: Or, hmm, it would be a (very small) improvement to say that $x\sim y$ iff there are $m,n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f^m(x) = f^n(y)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Does the interpretation with connected components follow from the description I mentioned? I don't see how these components come into picture.

Comment: @user634426: That's exactly that the last paragraph in the question says, just in graph-theoretic language instead.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x$ we know that $x \sim fx$. In particular we also have that $fx \sim ffx$, and then inductively $x \sim f^nx$ for every $n$. Finally we can conclude that $f^mx = f^ny$ implies $x \sim y$. Since "$x \approx y$ iff $f^mx = f^ny$ for some $m$, $n$" is an equivalence relation and we've shown that $\approx ⊆ \sim$, it follows that $\sim = \approx$.

For general $f$ we can't do better than this, ie. than saying that $x \sim y$ if their orbits under $f$ intersect.

This simplifies if $f$ is invertible. Then we have $x \sim f^kx$ for every $k ∈ ℤ$ (because $f^{-1}x \sim f(f^{-1}x) = x$) and the distinct sets $\{f^kx : k ∈ ℤ\}$ are disjoint, so that $X/{\sim}$ can be succinctly described as the orbit space of the group action associated to $f$ (ie. the action $φ : ℤ → X^X$ such that $φ(1) = f$).

Comment: I don't think the last paragraph is true. For example, consider $X=\mathbb Z$ and $f(x)=x+1$. This is invertible. But $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ are distinct orbits (of $0$ and $1$, respectively) but not disjoint.

Comment: You're right, of course. I was thinking about the associated group action, but then you need to take the entire $\{ f^kx : k ∈ ℤ \}$ for the "orbit" of $x$.